# Error while importing Python code - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'make_DB'

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling

I know this is a very common error and is usually resolved by renaming modules or correcting imports (from what I could figure out), but I've tried different suggestions I found on stackoverflow that didn't work, so I'm posting yet another AttributeError question.

I have a code called build_database.py that calls another as follows :

```
import csv
import os
import make_sig_files
import add_to_DB_tables

... 
    ## Calls to 2 other python codes...
    make_sig_files.make_files() # works!
    add_to_DB_tables.make_DB(repoURL) # AttributeError :(

...
```

Here is what add_to_DB_tables.py looks like :

```
import boto.dynamodb2
from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table
from boto.dynamodb2.items import Item
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from collections import defaultdict
import time
import sys,os
import subprocess

def main():
    make_DB("some_repo_URL")

def make_DB(repoURL):
    ...

## some other functions here...

if  __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the error that is produced on running build_databases.py :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "build_database.py", line 26, in <module>
        add_to_DB_tables.make_DB(repoURL)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'make_DB'
```

Also, if it helps, here's what make_sig_files.py looks like :

```
import sys,os
import subprocess
from subprocess import check_output
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def main():
    make_files()

def make_files():
    ...

## some other functions here...

if  __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

I did also try deleting all .pyc files in the directory in which I'm running this, and it didn't help. Also, add_to_DB_tables.py works perfectly fine if run from the command line. Any pointers/suggestions much appreciated!